# Antelope contiki-OS

Tags: python, c, contiki

I just started studying Contiki-OS. 
And I am interested in Contiki - Antelope.
I try to the AQL (Antelope Query Language) to create relation, attribute and insert tuples in  serial Cooja simulation. Like this:

```
create relation simple;
create attribute id domain int in sample;
create attribute temp domain int in sample;
insert (1,1) into sample;
insert (2.2) into sample;
....
```

But, I don't know how to insert auto about 1000 tuples?
I can't do this manual like:

```
insert (1,1) into sample;
insert (2.2) into sample;
.....
inser (1000,1000) into sample;
```

How to add 1000 tuples automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contiki contains an Antelope example that automatically inserts a user-specified number of tuples into a database. See the file examples/antelope/netdb/netdb-server.c in the Contiki source code.

Notice also that there are several typos in the commands and queries listed in your question, which may cause of some the problems.